# How to replace the string in a paragraph based on expression using PHP

Tags: php

Here I have a sample paragraph `$input_str`

```
$input_str = 'Some text is here......[$radio_yes: He is eligible for PF. / $radio_no: He is not eligible for PF.]....Some text is here';
$control_name = 'radio_yes';
```

Replace the paragraph content `$input_str` based on `$control_name`.

```
 if($control_name=='radio_yes') Then
    {
        I want to the result : $result_str = 'Some text is here......He is eligible for PF......Some text is here';
    }
    else if($control_name=='radio_no') Then
    {
        I want to the result :  $result_str = 'Some text is here......He is not eligible for PF.....Some text is here';
    }
```

Really I don't know the PHP string function.
How to do by using string functions or other ways. 
Thanks to all.

Comment: does your `$input_str` change ? is this just an example ?

Comment: I've posted an answer that should help you.

Comment: You may want to take a look at my updated answer, there was no need for the switch as @Toto mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to split the `$input_str` into 3 parts, **before**, **controller** and **after**. <strike>Then we use a switch based on the `$control_name`</strike>  and lastly we match the text associated with that `controller` and put together the pieces, i.e.:

```
<?php

$input_str = 'Some text is here......[$radio_yes: He is eligible for PF. / $radio_no: He is not eligible for PF.]....Some text is here';
$control_name = 'radio_yes';

preg_match_all('/^(.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*?)$/si', $input_str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$before = $matches[1][0];
$controllerRaw = $matches[2][0];
$after = $matches[3][0];

preg_match_all("/$control_name:(.*?)\./si", $controllerRaw, $controller, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$controller = $controller[1][0];
echo "$before $controller $after";
```

---

The above code should work with any `$input_str` as long as the pattern is the same, `some text... [ controller: some text ending with. ] more text...`

---

[IdeoneDemo](https://ideone.com/tN3m23)

Comment: No, but it's will spare some resources compared to `if` ;)

Comment: `if` is not mandatory too. The two sets of instructions are strictly the same.

Comment: Suppose my input string is without dot(.) then it will show the error For EX: `$input_str = 'Some text is here......[$radio_yes: He is eligible for **PF /** $radio_no: He is not eligible for PF]....Some text is here';`

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = preg_match('~/(.*?)]~', $input_str, $output);
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner and it will never be code only, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Your input text;
$input_string = 'Some text is here......[$radio_yes: He is eligible for PF. / $radio_no: He is not eligible for PF.]....Some text is here';

//The text inside the input text you want to be replaced:
$pattern = '/[\$radio_yes: He is eligible for PF. / \$radio_no: He is not eligible for PF.]/'

//conditional that decides what the $pattern will be replaced with:
if($control_name=='radio_yes')
{
  $replaceWith = 'He is eligible for PF';
}
else($control_name=='radio_no')
{
  $replaceWith = 'He is not eligible for PF';
}

//replacing the $pattern and giving the result to $newString
$newString = preg_replace($pattern, $replaceWith, $input_string);

echo $newString;//printing out the results
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: Assume : `$control_name='radio_no'; `I am getting Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\report_writer\test3.php on line 25

Comment: I think Your answer have very small mistake. Please correct it.

Comment: @RamaLingam  have corrected it, try now. what I did was replace $ with \$ (escaping the special character). Let me know now if it works.

Comment: RESULT : SHe is eligible for PFmHe is eligible for PFHe is eligible for PFHe is eligible for PFHe is eligible for PFxHe is eligible for PF...................... More times printed..

Answer (score 0):

Such regex takes names and values of radios from your string. And preg_replace_callback can change it by control_name value. If control_name is not     equal to any found value, it returns empty string

```
echo preg_replace_callback('~\[\$(\w+):(.+)/\s*\$(\w+):(.+)\]~', 
     function($m) use ($control_name) {
       if ($control_name == $m[1]) 
          return $m[2];
       if ($control_name == $m[3]) 
          return $m[4];
       return "";
     },
     $input_str);
```

[demo](https://eval.in/560673)